# Middle vertical-align on inline-block's without setting height

Tags: html, css

This seems so simple but I can't get it right.

My `work-features` box aligns to the bottom. I've tried to use `vertical-align: middle` but that makes it worse.

I'd rather not set a fixed height, use float's, or jQuery to accomplish this. Also can't change the HTML inside the `<div class="work">` block.

I have read some of the others questions on SO but none of the solutions worked for me.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/310daqpv/)**

**HTML**

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="entry" lang="en">
        <div class="work">
            <ul class="work-features">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Cras facilisis urna in vulputate vehicula.</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="work-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum elit nec elementum tincidunt. Duis pharetra vehicula odio sit amet rhoncus. Cras id est tincidunt, dictum lacus id, venenatis orci. Nulla consequat nunc nec nisl blandit, non porta ipsum rhoncus. Praesent eleifend bibendum dignissim. Pellentesque a scelerisque dolor, nec auctor eros. Nam eu nunc nisl. Quisque sed varius lorem. Suspendisse a tellus vel lacus elementum mollis ac ut turpis. Morbi scelerisque viverra dignissim. Curabitur id semper nisi, in eleifend elit. Pellentesque dapibus auctor erat, a posuere eros.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside;
}
.entry .work .work-features {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
}
.entry .work .work-features li {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.entry .work .work-description {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 640px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: [Try this cool site out](http://howtocenterincss.com/) on centering. It will generate the code for you even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you tried adding `vertical-align: middle` to `.work-features`. You should also add it to `.work-description` in order to make it work.

```css
.work-features, .work-description {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
ol, ul {
  list-style: none outside;
}
.entry .work .work-features {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
.entry .work .work-features li {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.entry .work .work-description {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 640px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.work-features, .work-description {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <div class="entry" lang="en">
    <div class="work">
      <ul class="work-features">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Cras facilisis urna in vulputate vehicula.</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="work-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi elementum elit nec elementum tincidunt. Duis pharetra vehicula odio sit amet rhoncus. Cras id est tincidunt, dictum lacus id, venenatis orci. Nulla consequat nunc nec nisl blandit, non porta ipsum rhoncus. Praesent eleifend bibendum dignissim. Pellentesque a scelerisque dolor, nec auctor eros. Nam eu nunc nisl. Quisque sed varius lorem. Suspendisse a tellus vel lacus elementum mollis ac ut turpis. Morbi scelerisque viverra dignissim. Curabitur id semper nisi, in eleifend elit. Pellentesque dapibus auctor erat, a posuere eros.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Jeez, the only thing I didn't try, adding it to both blocks. Seems weird to me to have to do that. Thank you!